# How do I merge Streams in Futures 0.2?

Tags: rust, future

As stated [in the documentation for Futures 0.1](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.11/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.merge), `Stream` provided a `merge` method to merge two `Stream`s. What is the equivalent in Futures **0.2**?

I do not want to zip the `Stream`s.

Comment: What will be the future use of futures in Futures 0.3, only future know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you review the [most recent documentation for `Stream` in 0.1.21](https://docs.rs/futures/0.1.21/futures/stream/trait.Stream.html#method.merge), you will see this note:

> Deprecated: functionality provided by `select` now

`select` is a method of the [`StreamExt` trait](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2/futures/trait.StreamExt.html#method.select).